# Problem on register/login widgets

Tags: widgets

I have downloaded and uploaded, activated successfully the plugin : Sidebar login of wordpress.org, which can be found here : [Sidebar login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sidebar-login/screenshots/)

In the picture description of sidebar login(in the link above), there is register link, so that people can use it to generate a new username via email. However, in my blog, it has only the forget password link : 
[image]

So, what was the problem ?

I beg your pardon for my question if you feel my question is not appropriate. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: No one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I just need to enable the option anyone can register in my settings.

Sorry if my question made you lost time.